# sidebar in all categories

Tags: wordpress

I have more than 20 categories in WordPress website. Can somebody help me here to show sidebar in all categories. Like when user click categories 1 sidebar should be visible there. any plugin or any other trick? Please response soon.

Answer (score 0):

Can you be clear on this?

I am getting confused, you can simply add catogories widget will display on catogories with numbers on right side bar

If you  elaborate it that would be great I am very happy to answer your questions

Thanks